# Deleting a remote tracking branch in git

Tags: git

I deleted my branch named `branchName` by using `git branch -d branchName`.

After that I wanted to delete its remote tracking branch too. So I did like this  `git branch -d remotes/origin/branchName` but I am getting
`error: branch 'remotes/origin/branchName` not found. Why?

When I do `git branch -a` , I can see the reference `remotes/origin/branchName` exists.

I know that if we do `git push origin :branchName` , remote tracking branch will be removed by that but why not by `git branch -d` after all it is just a reference ? Also what is the meaning of the error message ?

Comment: A classic. See [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely).

Comment: in [git branch docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#_description) , `Use -r together with -d to delete remote-tracking branches.`